# Как удалить пробелы в конце строки четных чисел?

Tags: java

На вход подаётся целое число n > 1. Сформируйте массив чётных чисел от 2 до n (включительно).

Выведите на печать массив в одной строке, через пробел.

Посчитайте и выведите на печать сумму элементов массива.

```
Sample Input:

10
Sample Output:

2 4 6 8 10
30
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Example {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numb = inp.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 2; i <= numb;i += 2) {
            sum += i;
            System.out.print(i);
            if (i <= numb) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n" + sum);
    }
```

```
Failed test #1 of 6. Wrong answer

This is a sample test from the problem statement!

Test input:
10
Correct output:
2 4 6 8 10
30
        
Your code output:
2 4 6 8 10 
30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так (при условии, что `n` четное):

```
if (i < numb) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Или так (без разницы, четное или нечётное)

```
if (i != numb && i != numb - 1) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Task {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Пожалуйста, введите число: ");
        int sum = 0;
        int number = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        for(int i=2; i<=number; i+=2) {
            numbers.add(i);
            sum+=i;
        } 
        for(Integer num : numbers) 
            System.out.print(num+" ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(sum);
    } 
}
```